# Chromecast does not resume after pause with error 2100

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

I recently updated my application from the old CastCompanionLibrary to Chromecast SDK3 and although play and seek work normally, I can't resume playback after pause. I am logging the error as follows

```
player.play().setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                        Log.d("cast", "SUCCESS");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                        Log.d("cast", "FAILURE "+status.getStatusMessage());
                    }
                });
```

The failure reason is always `2100 FAILED, the in progress request failed`.
I also updated the receiver application to use the default Styled Media Receiver but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

**SOLUTION**

The problem was that I was calling

```
remoteClient.load(myMediaInfo, true, position);
remoteClient.play();
```

It turns out that if you load the MediaInfo with `autoplay=true`, you are not allowed to directly call `play()`. If you do, the video starts playing and can be paused and seeked but can never be resumed. Play always fails with the error above. I think the framework could handle this a bit better or at least give a decent error message, which can lead to some kind of conclusion, which is not the case with 2100 FAILED.

Comment: What sort of media is this? For example, is it live stream? And also, what do you see on the receiver logs?

Comment: @AliNaddaf thank you but I found the problem (see above). It was a normal HLS stream and receiver logs didn't show anything abnormal.